# Looping for each cell in range doesnt return any values i want, and i get no error in my code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make this simple loop work, I get no errors when i press Run sub but no values show up in column W. I'm trying to return the value in column R when the corresponding value in column N is "sell". What's my glaring mistake here?

```
For Each cell In Range("n62:n166")

     If cell.Value = "sell" Then
     Range("r" & cell.Row) = Range("w" & cell.Row)

     End If
Exit For
Next
```

Thanks so much guys. I'm new to VBA so I'm still really bad at this. Thanks.

Comment: if you are looping through a single column, it will be easier to use `For lRow = 62 to 166` , then just compare `If Cells(lRow,"N").Value = "Sell" Then` , and at the end use `Cells(lRow, "W").Value = Cells(lRow, "R").Value` and you're done, and why do you have the `Exit For` in your loop ???

Comment: read my comment above, why do you have `Exit For` in you `For` loop ? What is the worksheet name you want to run this code?

Comment: Hi @shairado, I've tried that method prior to posting this and i just tried it again, it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Do you want to exit the loop after the first 'sell' value is found? Or do you want to do that for all 'sell' values?

Comment: @jadeliew123 what is your worksheet name ?

Comment: I've changed it to exit cell and added Sheets("Sheet2").activate, I still don't know why I can't get a figure. I've tried everything to make sure im on the right sheet like returning "hello" on another cell, and it worked. just not returning the value of the corresponding cell row.

Comment: @ShaiRado my worksheet name is "sheet2",

Comment: @V.K. I want to do it for all sell values. this is only part of a code that is more complex, and I narrowed down my error to this small part which I found out couldn't work.

Comment: Are your string comparisons case sensitive? Maybe you have `SELL` in your column N and you compare it to `sell`. Try to use `Option Compare Text` at the very beginning of your module (as the first line). This will make your comparisons in that module case insensitive.

Comment: ...and are the values in column N really only pure 'sell'? Don't you have some leading or trailing spaces there? This often happens when one copies stuff from elsewhere, e.g. from HTML page...

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you specify the sheet for all the range calls and make the comparison case-insensitive

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
For Each cell In .Range("n62:n166")

     If Trim$(Lcase$(cell.Value2)) = "sell" Then
     .Range("r" & cell.Row).Value2 = .Range("w" & cell.Row).Value2

     End If
Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy values from column R to column W (which is what I understood from your question), then you should write this:
`Range("W" & cell.Row) = Range("R" & cell.Row)`. Moreover There should be no `Exit For` and use `Next cell` instead of just `Next`.

```
For Each cell In Range("n62:n166")
    If cell.Value = "sell" Then
        Range("W" & cell.Row).Value = Range("R" & cell.Row).Value
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: hi VK, thanks for your comment. I've tried both those changes before posting this, and those didn't work! :<

Comment: It still doesn't work unfortunately.. tried those changes :/

Comment: Maybe you are working in wrong sheet... To check this put `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` before your code to check that you have correct active sheet... And if it does not work, what does it do? Nothing? Or some error?

Comment: I've added Sheets("sheet2").activate but it still doesn't work!

Comment: so try to trace it with debugger. if you are learning VBA, you will need to work with debugger anyway... or if you do not want debugger, try to put `msgbox cell.value` before the line with `if`. This will let you check you are working with correct cells with the values you expect. Or alternatively you can write `Debug.Print cell.Value` and then view the results in Immediate widnow (you need to switch it on somewhere in View menu).

Comment: after using debugger you should be able to tell if the problem is that the code does not correctly recognize 'sell' values or whether there is problem copying values from R to W.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the value of the Cell in column R to the value in column W for rows that meet the requirements (`value = "Sell"`)? if so, you're missing the `.Value` piece - Here:

```
For Each cell In Range("N62:N166")
     If Trim(WorksheetFunction.Proper(Cell.Value)) = "Sell" Then Range("R" & Cell.Row).Value = Range("W" & Cell.Row).Value
Next
```

Comment: Using `Value` is a good practice but is not strictly necessary here. I believe `Value` is the default property of a cell object.

Comment: @V.K. You're right - I'm just after seeing the problem now (I corrected it in my code without realizing it) - After one iteration you'll get kicked out of the loop because of the `Exit for`

Comment: @jadeliew123 If my first code didn't work it's a case that you're data quality is not right ("sell", "Sell" and "Sell " are all separate values) - I've changed the code to account for this and should work now

Comment: @jadeliew123 Also, do you want it to keep looping through to row 166 or stop once you hit the first cell with Sell in it? - Judging from you original code, you were trying to stop after one (so that's what I have in)

Comment: @Jeremy hi Jeremy, i wanted to keep looping to row 166 because this is only a small part of my more complex code. how would the code be like if i wanted to keep looping to row 166 instead of just finding the first cell?

Comment: @jadeliew123 Done!